# How to replay a list of event consistently

Tags: c++, python, windows

I have a file containing a list of event spaced with some time. Here is an example:

```
0, Hello World
0.5, Say Hi
2, Say Bye
```

I would like to be able to replay this sequence of events. The first column is the delta between the two consecutive events ( the first starts immendiately, the second happens 0.5s later, the third 2s later, ... )

How can i do that on Windows . Is there anything that can ensure that I am very accurate on the timing ? The idea is to be as close as what you would have listneing some music , you don't want your audio event to happen close to the right time but just on time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily by using the `sleep` function from the `time` module. The exact code should work like this:

```
import time

# Change data.txt to the name of your file
data_file = open("data.txt", "r")

# Get rid of blank lines (often the last line of the file)
vals = [i for i in data_file.read().split('\n') if i]

data_file.close()

for i in vals:
    i = i.split(',')
    i[1] = i[1][1:]
    time.sleep(float(i[0]))

    print i[1]
```

This is an imperfect algorithm, but it should give you an idea of how this can be done. We read the file, split it to a newline delimited list, then go through each comma delimited couplet sleeping for the number of seconds specified, and printing the specified string.

Comment: Yes I already come accross this solution but was wondering if we could achieve a more accurate result. The Timer api(as far I know) is not enough accurate to properly simulate. My simple example did not shows the real application behind the scene but I do need the best accuracy available on Windows (that is why I was thinking calling directly the Win32 C api maybe)

Comment: I suspected that might be the case. Since the print statement takes up time (as does splitting up the strings), this algorithm will be inaccurate because the time required will always be slightly greater than specified in the file. One simple solution comes from hobbyist game programming. 

Their solution is to record the time at the beginning of the loop, and at the end of the loop (before we sleep), get the difference between the start and end time, and subtract that from the amount we sleep by. That will give you a much more accurate (though still technically imperfect) delay.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`time.sleep(...)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) in Python.

If you load that file as a list, and then print the values,

```
import time

with open("datafile.txt", "r") as infile:
   lines = infile.read().split('\n')

   for line in lines:
      wait, response = line.split(',')
      time.sleep(float(wait))
      print response
```

Comment: See my comment on Maxwell answer. Your solution works fine but not sure about the accuracy part of my question.

Comment: In that case, your best bet is probably functional programming--to have those functions called as part of whatever you're doing, so that you have guaranteed perfected timing--the function will only be called when the calling function ends, to ensure that you don't have to manually line up `time.sleep` periods.  That's really the only way to do that.